# Use pandoc/latex on Docker with LuaLaTeX PDF engine and TeX Gyre Fonts

Tags: luatex, pandoc, luaotfload

## Motivation

Original question from [pandoc discuss](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/p5ABArKwgQ4/m/DE-99YBoBAAJ).

To build an Docker image allowing `pandoc --pdf-engine=lualatex test.md -o test.pdf` with the source file `test.md` as follow:

```
---
mainfont: TeX Gyre Termes
---

Lorem ipsum ttt
```

## Background info about pandoc's Docker image

The [official Docker image `pandoc/latex:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/pandoc/latex) installed [TeXLive under `/opt`](https://github.com/pandoc/dockerfiles/blob/9845ae4bb7f099779fe808e2ca59649e87e46289/alpine/latex.Dockerfile#L21) whose write access is reserved for root user.  By default, a container is run with root.

```
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint="" pandoc/latex:latest sh -c 'whoami'
root
```

> To run pandoc using Docker, converting README.md to README.pdf:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --rm --volume "$(pwd):/data" --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
> pandoc/latex README.md -o README.pdf
> ```
>
> source: [pandoc installing #Docker](https://pandoc.org/installing.html#docker)

> ! `$(pwd)` takes everything in current directory to `/data` in the Docker container built from image `pandoc/latex:latest`, then the container runs `pandoc README.md -o README.pdf` with the user and group privileges in the base system, and ends, The output `README.pdf` remains after the container has ended.  The `--rm` is included so that it's not recorded in the list of containers `docker ps`.

## Background info about Docker's `USER`

To avoid running as root in a Docker container, one can [specify the `USER name` in `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/search?q=USER%20pptruser&type=code).

## Question

I tried compiling `test.md` with [my `Dockerfile`](https://gitlab.com/VincentTam/pandoc-mermaid-docker/-/blob/7f259241ee4ef222302bd8a6d670cc7d6c7afd60/Dockerfile), which used the identity `USER pptruser` of a normal user, and I got an unhelpful message showing a "fatal error".  To know more about the problem, I first converted `test.md` to `test.tex` locally with

```
$ pandoc -s test.md -o test.tex
```

before I compiled it with LuaLaTeX in the Docker container built with [my `Dockerfile`](https://gitlab.com/VincentTam/pandoc-mermaid-docker/-/blob/7f259241ee4ef222302bd8a6d670cc7d6c7afd60/Dockerfile).

```
$ docker run --rm --volume "$(pwd):/home/pptruser" --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
customDockerImage:1.0 --pdf-engine=lualatex test.md -o test.pdf
```

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./201113-TAM-compte-rendu.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2



luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load "fontloader" module "basics-gen".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:306: system : no writeable cache path, quiting".

stack traceback:
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:174: in local 'load_fontloader_module'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:308: in upvalue 'init_main'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:560: in function 'luaotfload-init.lua'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:298: in field 'main'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk

...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:306: system : no wr
iteable cache path, quiting
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:306: in function '
os.exit'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:177: in local 'loa
d_fontloader_module'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:308: in upvalue 'i
nit_main'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:560: in function '
luaotfload-init.lua'
    ...dir/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:298: in field 'mai
n'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
<everyjob> ...ring \\def\string \\encodingdefault{OT1}')end }
                                                  \let \f@encoding \encoding...

l.1 
  % Options for packages loaded elsewhere
```

The `no writeable cache path` from `luaotfload` caused the error.  I observed that if I remove the `USER pptruser` related settings and run everything as root, then the error is gone.

I wonder if there's a way to build a `Dockerfile` so that the compilation of `test.md` containing the font TeX Gyre Termes with LuaLaTeX PDf engine works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is incredible simple: identify the "writable cache path", and give it the write permission to everyone.  In the Docker image, pandoc/latex:latest, it's `/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-var`.

I resolved this issue at [commit VincentTam/pandoc-mermaid-docker@`d86343f0`](https://gitlab.com/VincentTam/pandoc-mermaid-docker/-/commit/d86343f0844115a20605fb9a3cf434311d5873d0) on GitLab by appending

```
chmod o+w /opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-var
```

to the `RUN` command that created the user `pptruser` (somewhere before changing to a normal user from root).

Comment: I was having a similar issue and this solution was spot on. Thanks man!